# How to install b43 on brcm 47xx?

Tags: openwrt

I am using the OpenWRT"brcm-47xx-" on linksyswrt54GL v1.1. I have tried to install b43 using

"insmod b43 qos=0"

but an error is thrown

insmod: can't insert 'b43': File exists

this command is to install  the driver b43 which create b43 folder in the kernel directory "/usr/kernel/debug/"

```
root@OpenWrt:/sys/kernel/debug# ls
bdi        ieee80211  mips
```

where I expect to have b43 folder contain the files in the following image:

[the debug/b43/phy0/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbKnh.png)

```
    root@OpenWrt:/# cat /etc/openwrt_release
    DISTRIB_ID="OpenWrt"
    DISTRIB_RELEASE="10.03.1"
    DISTRIB_CODENAME="backfire"
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="OpenWrt Backfire 10.03.1"
```

```
 root@OpenWrt:# opkg info kmod-b43
Package: kmod-b43
Version: 2.6.32.27+2011-11-15-1
Depends: kernel (= 2.6.32.27-1), kmod-mac80211
Provides:
Status: install user installed
Architecture: brcm47xx
Installed-Time: 1324443071
```

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds like the driver is already loaded. Check `lsmod`. // Also note that `insmod` expects a filename, unlike `modprobe`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer' yes but I checked the kernel folder I couldn't see the b43 folder which is supposed to be there

Comment: and also I cant use modprobe

Comment: Of course, OpenWrt offers only `insmod`. Please add the output of `opkg info kmod-b43` and `cat /etc/openwrt_release` to your question.

Comment: Hello  Daniel B, I added the output. I hope you are able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled my WRT54GL out of the tech heap. Here’s the results:

- `insmod: can't insert 'b43': File exists` does indeed indicate the module is already loaded

  - Your driver is working correctly.
- There is no `/sys/kernel/debug/b43`. The driver was most likely built without this feature to save space. The corresponding kernel option is called `B43_DEBUG`.

This means you have to create a new kmod-b43 package. I tried to do so but couldn’t get the OpenWrt SDK to run, mainly because their SVN server is down.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer . I really need to run b43 with openfwwf for my master thesis. here is one of the versions that b43 is work. but I was not able to configure the router to work as AP. http://netweb.ing.unibs.it/~openfwwf/firmware/openwrt-brcm47xx-squashfs.trx

Comment: That firmware release is made specifically for the “jamming” test they performed. It probably runs a very specialized version of the driver. If you really have to, I suggest you get on the OpenWrt forums and explain what you want to do (access b43 debug options) and why you need it. You can also start by looking into the [OpenWrt Build System](https://wiki.openwrt.org/about/toolchain) which you will probably need.

Comment: Thank you. I will ask in Openwrt Forum and try to figure out how to do it.

Comment: please accept my apologies for asking many questions. I will try your suggestion. But I am looking also for another solution for example if there is any cheap external Broadcom wireless USB that I can run b43 on it, and I can run my laptop as an accesspoint. if it is possible. please if you have any information and useful links can you provide me because I don't have much time for my master thesis

Comment: The b43 driver doesn’t support USB devices, so that won’t work. It’s also not entirely clear what exactly your requirements are. Is it just about the OpenFWWF firmware and the debug directory?

Comment: yes, I have modified openFWWF and save the measurement data that I need into the shared memory. thus, I need the debug to be able to read the shared memory only if there are any way to read the shared memory that openFWWF uses it will solve my problem.